# Regex match for a non-english language in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.x

I'm trying to capture and match russian language characters in a python script. Since russian characters don't fall in [a-Z] type, what regex should I should to match them. I can't use a (.*) because it would match everything.

```
linkpat = re.compile('name=[a-Z]+;size=[0-9]+')
```

Comment: By the way, `[a-Z]` is not a valid range.

Comment: @Tim Yea. I didn't copy the code verbatim. The actual regex is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use unicode flag:

```
re.compile('name=\w+;size=\d+', re.U)
```

this would also match any letter in any language (plus underscore), not just Russian, though.

Comment: Yea, it would do for me. And your solution is better since its possible that I may run into some unknown language as well at some stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `\w` with the correct [LOCALE](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.LOCALE)

Answer (score 0):

Use character classes, which are locale dependent